# Special case of the law of total probability

Tags: probability

I'm trying to compute the probability of a random variable $Y$ with support $\mathcal{Y}$ by conditioning on the events $X_i, i\in [1, \ldots, n]$ and using the law of total probability. This gives
$$
p(Y) = \sum\limits_{i=1}^n p(Y|X_i)p(X_i)
$$
by definition. The $X_i$s obey the conditions required by the law of total probability, that is they are mutually exclusive and partition the sample space. The "special case" is that $\forall i, p(X_i) = \frac{1}{n}$. That is, the $X_i$s have a uniform distribution. I conjecture that in this special case,
$$
\sum\limits_{y\in\mathcal{Y}}\sum\limits_{i=1}^n p(y|X_i) = n
$$
I sketched a simple proof, which is as follows:
\begin{align}
\sum\limits_{y\in\mathcal{Y}} p(y) &= 1\\
\sum\limits_{y\in\mathcal{Y}}\sum\limits_{i=1}^n p(y|X_i)p(X_i) &= 1\\
p(X_i)\sum\limits_{y\in\mathcal{Y}}\sum\limits_{i=1}^n p(y|X_i) &= 1\\
\sum\limits_{y\in\mathcal{Y}}\sum\limits_{i=1}^n p(y|X_i) &= \frac{1}{p(X_i)}\\
\end{align}
Am I correct, or have I made a mistake somewhere?

Comment: sure, looks right

Comment: Looks okay except for when you factorise $p(X_i)$ to outside the scope of the bound variable, $i$.  Since the function is uniform for all $i$, that should be: $$p(X_1)\sum_{y\in\mathcal Y}\sum_{i=1}^n p(y\mid X_i)=1$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Am I correct, or have I made a mistake somewhere?

It looks almost okay, save for a technical error.   You factorised $p(X_i)$ to outside the scope of the bound variable, $i$.

However, when ${(X_i)}_{i=1}^n$ is a sequence of identically distributed random variables (uniformly distribution) then:

$$\begin{align}
\sum\limits_{y\in\mathcal{Y}} p(y) &= 1\\
\sum\limits_{y\in\mathcal{Y}}\sum\limits_{i=1}^n p(y\mid X_i)p(X_i) &= 1\\
p(X_1)\sum\limits_{y\in\mathcal{Y}}\sum\limits_{i=1}^n p(y\mid X_i) &= 1\\
\sum\limits_{y\in\mathcal{Y}}\sum\limits_{i=1}^n p(y\mid X_i) &= \frac{1}{p(X_1)}\\ &= n
\end{align}$$